# What is the reasoning behind java.util.Collections.binarySearch return value, when the key isn't found?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)) it says that `java.util.Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)` returns...

> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list;
>   **otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)**. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list:
>   the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if
>   all elements in the list are less than the specified key...

My question is, what significance (if any) does the theorem `(-(insertion point) - 1)` have such that it's the return value when a key isn't found? Why not just return `insertion point` for instance?

Comment: How would you then distinguish between found and not-found?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: By comparing `key` to the value at that index. If such comparisons consumed a significant proportion of runtime, I can see how you'd want to minimize them, and if the list isn't random-access, I can see how you'd want to avoid the traversal, but encoding this information in the sign is a mess. Too bad Java doesn't have any support for multiple return values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, if the element is not found, a negative value must be returned according to the documetation, or you cannot distinguish between found and not found.

Ok, so why not just `-insertion point`? Imagine if the insertion point is 0 (the searched element is smaller than all existing ones), then that logic would break - not found would return a non-negative number. Hence the extra `-1`.

Ok, so why not just `-1` always?

Because knowing the insertion point of a non-match in a sorted list is useful to find answers to questions such as:

> What is the next element that is bigger than the one I ask for?

and

> How many elements are larger than the one I (didn't) find?

And, the way binary search works, the algorithm knows this index when it terminates, so why not share it when it costs nothing extra?

Answer (score 0):

From the same docs, the return value must be >= 0 if the key exists. `insertion point` could be zero if all elements are greater than the key, leading to a return value of zero even though the key does not exist. On the other hand, the value `(-(insertion point) - 1)` is always less than zero.

> Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to combine two use cases into one method call. `List.indexOf()` and similar methods will simply return -1 when an element is not found, but `Collections.binarySearch()` goes one step further and returns a negative number that is also useful when you're building a sorted list element by element.